# Testing for redstone dust in a certain area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In a 13x13 area, command blocks should locate any redstone dust currently placed, and change the block beneath it to wood planks.

But, I see no possible way to do this, or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe you have stumbled upon one of the bigger issues with command blocks. They suck at locating *blocks*. You *could* teleport an armor stand around, but this is fairly slow (1 block per tick, so 8,5s total for a 13x13x1 area) and requires some effort. Or you can summon 169 armor stands at the cost of summoning 169 armor stands :)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind using mods, I would maybe know some solution (writing a mod for that)

Comment: @MrLemon it's enough to testfor blocks only around the player (which placed the dust): 25 instead of 169 ArmorStands :D

Answer (score 1):

My best idea is to summon 169 (13 x 13) armor stands, one on each block (you probably want to name them something too). Then you would run a command such as:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=SOMENAMEHERE] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ redstone_dust 0 /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ planks
```

Or if 169 armor stands causes too much lag, you could decrease the amount of armor stands by only summoning one armor stand for every 2 blocks, running the execute command, teleporting all the armor stands 1 block forward, and running the command again. Note that this method will take 2 ticks to run whereas the first can do everything in 1 tick.